# A criterion for divisors of degree $n$ on the projective line to belong to a linear system of codimension 1

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, divisors

My question is essentially about linear dependence/independence of polynomials, but I will formulate it in the language of algebraic geometry, hoping someone may suggest a result in algebraic geometry which may help me, hopefully!

Let $\mathbb{P}^1$ denote the complex projective line. I am working over the complex numbers. If $n$ is a fixed positive integer, then the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(n)$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$ has an $n+1$-dimensional space of holomorphic sections, corresponding to an $n$-dimensional complete linear system of divisors of $\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $n$.

I am interested in codimension $1$ linear systems of divisors in the previous complete linear system. One way to describe them, which also links them to the classical notion of apolarity, is as follows. Given a nonzero complex polynomial $q(z)$ of degree at most $n$, the space of all complex polynomials $p(z)$ which are $n$-apolar to $q(z)$ (by which I mean the usual notion of apolarity between complex polynomials of degree $n$, extended in a natural way to complex polynomials of degree at most $n$, using the same formula; I can explain more if required) is a subspace of $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(n))$ of codimension $1$, which I will denote by $V_q$. The divisors corresponding to elements of $V_q$ form an $n-1$-dimensional linear system of divisors, of codimension $1$ with respect to the corresponding complete linear system of divisors corresponding to $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(n))$.

Suppose given finitely many divisors, say $r$ of them, corresponding to $\mathcal{O}(n)$, is there a criterion to determine whether or not those divisors all belong to $V_q$, for some nonzero complex polynomial $q(z)$ of degree at most $n$? The question is trivial if $r \leq n$, because in this case there are too few divisors, so we can always find at least one such $V_q$ to which they all belong. The problem becomes non-trivial if $r \geq n + 1$. I am actually mostly interested in the case $r = n + 1$.

An obvious criterion in this case is to construct, to each given divisor, the corresponding section of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ (which is of course a polynomial in $z$ of degree at most $n$) and then the problem becomes whether or not the $r$ polynomials are linearly dependent (in which case there is a $V_q$ containing all the given divisors) or not. If $r = n + 1$, the matrix containing the coefficients of the $r$ polynomials becomes square, and we can resort to studying whether or not the determinant of that matrix vanishes.

I am aware of this criterion, but I wonder whether or not it can be reformulated in a more geometric language perhaps? This is why I formulated my question in the language of algebraic geometry, hoping the geometric side of things may illuminate the problem I am trying to solve (which is the Atiyah problem on configurations, where the divisors arise as sets of directions associated to $n + 1$ distinct points in Euclidean $3$-space; there is also a version of that problem where the $n + 1$ distinct points live in hyperbolic $3$-space).